# Get the second quarter of layout's heigth

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some difficulties with designing my app. My screen should contain toolbar and some edit fields. these fields should be places in the upper part of the screen under the toolbar. In the end it should look like this (sorry for quality of the image):

[image]

For this I decided to break the screen height into four equals parts and to pose my edit fields in the second quarter. I tried to use the following code to acchieve this, but it doesn't help: all the smaller relative layouts take all the screen. 
I also tried:

- to substitute the parent Relative layout with Linear layout
- to replace "fill_parent" with "wrap_content".

After these actions the smaller layouts simply disappear.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"      > 


    <include android:id = "@+id/toolbarLogo" layout="@layout/toolbar_logo"></include>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        >

        <EditText
            .../>

        <EditText
            ...
            />

        <Button
            .../>    

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Could you help me please with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your root layout to be a LinearLayout and ensure that the orientation is set to vertical. Change the layout_width of the children to be 1. See code below for an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f00"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0f0"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00f"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f0f"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It.. Set

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for each LinearLayout and 
set

```
android:weightSum="4"
```

for Parent LinearLayout and

Like This Example..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0ff"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#01a"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#101"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google library `PercentRelativeLayout` with this `library` you can set **width**, **height** and **margin** of your views by procentege which is great because in all screen they look the same and of course it is not hard to code it. Here example:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

you must add this line in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
}
```

**Official documentation by Google** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

And for your case should look maybe like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_heightPercent="40%">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondLayout"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"

        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.